# Displaying a notification from a wearable app

Tags: android, wear-os

trying to show a notification only on my wearable device, it appears I need to create a wearable app if I only want the notification to appear on the wearable device only according to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/layouts.html#CustomNotifications)

what I want is to see the notification with the basic information, user swipes to the left to see all the information (I guess that would be the activity from what the documentation says) then I want buttons to respond to that notification.

I am confused as to where I create the notification however, do I create the notification in the activity of the wearable app (the activity that displays the full information) or do I create it somewhere else?

Comment: The keyword is "custom."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the notification in your mobile app and notify using Notification manager.

Edit:
Didn't notice  that..

You can use Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage to send a message to wear app and in onMessageReceived method you can create the notification.

Comment: please read my question, I dont want to display the notification on my phone/tablet I only want to show it on the wearable. creating the notification on my phone/tablet with display it in both places